# Angular 2 pipes doesn't work with dot

Tags: angular

I want to show my date format so `{{credit.startDate | date:"dd.MM.yyyy" }}` , but my statement doesn't work. But this `{{credit.startDate | date:"dd/MM/yyyy" }}` works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a known issue with `date` pipe and custom formats https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7008

Answer (score 1):

The `date` pipe relies on `Intl.DateTimeFormat`. The pattern you provide when using this pipe is used to configure the formatter but you don't have the hand on the final string format. Otherwise the US-us locale applies when formatting (it's hard-coded at the moment).

Here is the way Angular2 configures options:

- https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/facade/intl.ts#L80

See this link for the `DateTimeFormat` object:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat